# Coding pipe "|" in C++: Why is a blank line entering getline after piping?

Tags: c++, pipe, fork, getline, dup2

I'm coding a mock shell and I'm currently working on coding pipes with dup2. Here is my code:

```
bool Pipe::execute() {
    int fds[2]; //will hold file descriptors
    pipe(fds);
    int status;
    int errorno;
    pid_t child;
    child = fork();

    if (-1 == child) {
        perror("fork failed");
    }
    if (child == 0) {
        dup2(fds[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fds[0]);
        close(fds[1]);
        this->component->lchild->execute();
        _exit(1);
    }
    else if (child > 0) {
        dup2(fds[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fds[0]);
        close(fds[1]);
        this->component->rchild->execute();
        waitpid(child, &status, 0);
        if ( WIFEXITED(status) ) {
            //printf("child exited with = %d\n",WEXITSTATUS(status));
            if ( WEXITSTATUS(status) == 0) {
                cout << "pipe parent finishing" << endl;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The `this->component->lchild->execute();` and `this->component->rchild->execute();` run `execvp` on the corresponding commands. I've confirmed that each of these return by printing out a statement in the parent process. However, in my `Pipe::execute()`, it seems like the child process does not finish because the cout statement in the parent process is never printed and I get a segmentation fault after the prompt (`$`) is initialized (see picture). Here is the main function that initializes the prompt after each execution:

```
int main()
{
    Prompt new_prompt;
    while(1) {
        new_prompt.initialize();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and here is the `initialize()` function:

```
void Prompt::initialize()
{
    cout << "$ ";
    std::getline(std::cin, input);

    parse(input);
    run();
    input.clear();
    tokens.clear();
    fflush(stdout);
    fflush(stdin);
    return;
}
```

It seems like `ls | sort` runs fine, but then when the prompt is initialized, a blank line is read into input by getline. I've tried using cin.clear(), cin.ignore, and the fflush and clear() lines above. This blank string is "parsed" and then the `run()` function is called, which tries to dereference a null pointer. Any ideas on why/where this blank line is being entered into getline? and how do I resolve this? Thank you!

UPDATE: The parent process in the pipe is now finishing. I've also noticed that I'm getting seg faults also for my I/O redirection classes (`>` and `<`). I think I'm not flushing the stream or closing the file descriptors correctly...

Here is my `execute()` function for lchild and rchild:

```
bool Command::execute() {
    int status;
    int errorno;
    pid_t child;
    vector<char *> argv;
    for (unsigned i=0; i < this->command.size(); ++i) {
        char * cstr = const_cast<char*>(this->command.at(i).c_str());
        argv.push_back(cstr);
    }
    argv.push_back(NULL);
    child = fork();
    if (-1 == child) {
        perror("fork failed");
    }
    if (child == 0) {
        errorno = execvp(*argv.data(), argv.data());
        _exit(1);

    } else if (child > 0) {
        waitpid(child, &status, 0);
        if ( WIFEXITED(status) ) {
            //printf("child exited with = %d\n",WEXITSTATUS(status));
            if ( WEXITSTATUS(status) == 0) {
                //cout << "command parent finishing" << endl;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's supposed to be like the shell terminal prompt - it waits for user input

Comment: Regardless of what's actually causing the blank line, I'd recommend the program _not_ segfault when running across one - perform checks and give an error as soon as possible rather than segfaulting.

Comment: After the update it is a different question that requires other parts of code. I suspect a similar issue there, but can't tell without seeing the code

Comment: @MichaelVeksler I added the execute function. This function should work for other command types also, so I'm afraid of closing one of the streams in it (for example, if I run echo hello && pwd, I don't want to close anything - only if I'm using redirection)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the bug:

```
else if (child > 0) {
    dup2(fds[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    close(fds[0]);
    close(fds[1]);
    this->component->rchild->execute();
```

You are closing stdin for the parent, not just the right child. After this the stdin of the parent process is the same as that of the right child.

After that

```
std::getline(std::cin, input);
```

Tries to read the output of the left child, rather than the original stdin. By that point the left child had finished and that end of the pipe had been closed. This makes reading stdin fail, and leave `input` unchanged in its original state.

Edit: Your design has a minor and a major flaws. The minor flaw is that you don't need the fork in `Pipe::execute`. The major flaw is that the child should be the one who redirects streams and closes the descriptors.

Simply pass input and output parameters through fork() and let the child dup2 these. Don't forget to make it also close unrelated pipe ends. If you don't, the left child will finish but its output pipe will continue living in other processes. As long as other copies of that descriptor live, the right child will never get EOF while reading its pipe end - and week block forever.

Comment: Ahhhh I see. So is there a way to "re-open" stdin? Or do I need to do an extra close somewhere?

Comment: @SarahAllec you should call `close` in the right child itself, not the parent

Comment: Well, there doesn't actually seem to *be* a right child, since there's only one call to `fork()`.  One parent, one (left) child.  At least, that's what there is at the level of `class Pipe`.

Comment: @BenVoigt look at the updated question. As I suspected the execute method calls fork, and that is the right child in there. I simply removed my note about this assumption, after the question was clarified

Comment: And now there are 3 children, which is still not the proper number of `fork()` calls, nor pipe-management in the correct child processes.

Comment: @BenVoigt exactly: two left (inner and outer), and one  right

Comment: @MichaelVeksler Going back to what you said before, I should put close(fds[0]) in the rchild's execute?